# How to generate a symmetric key with keysize of 256 using AES Algorithm on iOS?

Tags: ios, algorithm, encryption

I just started doing encryption for my strings in iOS and I have managed to encrypt and decrypt data using AES 256 using this method in CommonCrypto:

- (NSData *) AES256EncryptedDataUsingKey: (id) key error: (NSError **) error

It works for me and is great but now I am told to generate a symmetric key with keysize of 256 using AES algorithm.

How do i create a symmetric key on iOS? I looked into random generation of characters but I am not sure whether my random string is a symmetric key or not.

Comment: a key for a symetric cipher like AES is simply a bunch of random bits ... 

please be aware that there are pseudo random number generators (prngs) and cryptographic pseudo random number generators (cprngs) which differ in one thing: rngs for cryptographic use produce output that is hard to predict (in other words: closer to REAL randomness) ... for really critical stuff you will want a physical source for entropy

Comment: Read the very first answer of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17453750/how-do-encryption-algorithms-know-if-they-have-the-right-key